# Nested generic subtyping

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I am trying to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass <T extends AbstractClass<K extends ConcreteClass>>
```

I get an `Unexpected bound` error for K extends GenericJson, and I am not sure why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax to use is just a little different:

```
public class MyClass <K extends ConcreteClass, T extends AbstractClass<K>>
```

Or, if you don't care about `K`:

```
public class MyClass <T extends AbstractClass<? extends ConcreteClass>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what purpose are you trying to reach. Also, you can try to make it so:

```
public class MyClass <T extends AbstractClass<K>, K extends ConcreteClass> { }
```